# Where to get Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar document and how to modify styles globally for android?

Tags: android, styles, themes

After several hours' google, I found below path of all themes and styles attributes. But when I search the key word "AppCompat", found nothing. Where to get the document of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar like below links?

My goal is to modify the theme/style globally, see below illustration.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-6.0.1_r63/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-6.0.1_r63/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Illustration, for example, I would like to change the style of the toolbar title text. I need 2 steps, see below. I am thinking if I change Theme document directly, I don't need step-2. (assume I would like to change the style together for all toolbars).

In short, I don't modify a style for each widget/activity/etc., I would like to modify the global style which would apply to all widget/activity/etc.
Please help. Thanks.

1. define a style named Toolbar.TitleText;
2. use the style app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText".

   ```
   <style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
   <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
   </style>


   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For Android styles, you reference the preset attributes that Android has laid out in R.attr.for example for stylng  buttons you need to reference [buttonStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#buttonStyle) like below :

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think we are at same page. I know how to use a theme/style. But, for example, even I don't specify a style for a button, it still has a default style, right? What I ask is modify the default style file, so all buttons changed style...and don't need to quote the style for each button.

Comment: sorry, I don't mean modify the style file. I mean: modify style globally.